# First item in `listview` has `ui-btn-hover` class by default

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am sure this has to be a common issue but I can't find any reference in the internets.

I have a `listview` with jQuery Mobile UI:

```
<nav>
    <ul data-dividertheme="b" data-theme="c" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="categorias.html">Categorías</a></li>
        <li><a href="examenes.html">Exámenes</a></li>
        <li><a href="glosario.html">Glosario</a></li>
        <li><a href="preferencias.html">Preferencias</a></li>
        <li><a href="acerca.html">Acerca</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When rendered, by default the first `<li>` item has `class="ui-btn-hover-c"` thus appearingh highlighted. How can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the following threads which discuss the issue

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/latest-nightly-build-lists-and-ui-btn-hover

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-does-ui-btn-hover-a-appear-on-first-navbar-link

Comment: so right now the hack that works is putting `<span class="ui-title" style="display: none"></span>` before the firs list element, or, as I've done, just use the `class="ui-title"` in the text heading of the page.

Comment: Well as of now, thats the easy fix. Keep checking for the future release. They will fix it. Seems very less number of people have reported it